# Twitter Bootstrap navbar only toggles once when logged in

Tags: joomla, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a site in Joomla (unfortunately) for a client. I have installed a template that uses Bootstrap as its basis, with some integration with Joomla, called H5BPTB. The problem I'm having is that when I visit the homepage on a small screen, and toggle the responsive navbar, it works fine, however after logging in, the navbar will open once, then close, but then no longer responds unless I refresh the page.

I read a few references elsewhere on stackoverflow to this being a problem with missing CSS transitions in the `.collapse` class in Bootstrap CSS. I checked and they are not missing. I also read another answer that suggested that it was a problem with some other Javascript overriding `support.transition` in the Bootstrap JS. I also can't find a reference to that in any other JS file. Is there anything else this could be?

Also I should add that the navbar works perfectly well in IE, but not in Firefox or Chrome.

Here is the site: http://avantgardeinternational.eu

Comment: I tried to register, but it hasn't sent my account an email, I can't test it, if you can active my account, the email address is wright.elliot@gmail.com

Comment: It has a tendency to end up in spam. I'll activate you now.

Comment: I'd recommend just trying to update your Bootstrap files in the theme. They're both on version 2.1.1 and as far as I've seen looking around some people have had similar problems with earlier Bootstrap version. I'll post this as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend just trying to update your Bootstrap files in the theme. They're both on version 2.1.1 and as far as I've seen looking around some people have had similar problems with earlier Bootstrap version.

The files you're looking to change are:

http://avantgardeinternational.eu/templates/h5bptb/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://avantgardeinternational.eu/templates/h5bptb/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
http://avantgardeinternational.eu/templates/h5bptb/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js

If that doesn't work, I'd try just looking around and making sure that some scripts aren't conflicting, that could just mean disabling all but the Bootstrap JS. Then seeing if it works fine.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

**Edit**: Just attempted this, changing the CSS messed with the styles a bit, and it still didn't work. I don't think it loaded the JS into the page properly though, I'll try that now...

**Edit 2**: So after giving this a shot, I've concluded there is only one explanation now... I've observed the difference between the page when you're logged in and logged out. When you log in there are various other bits of JS that load into the page.

One of these must be overriding Bootstraps collapse methods, thus stopping it from working. There are a few extra scripts that load when you're logged in and some more styles. It might be working trying to remove these and then trying it again.

Comment: I tried updating the CSS and that didn't work. I'll have a look at the extra JS scripts now and see what I can do.

Comment: I'd just try get rid of almost every bit of JS you can, then add them back in one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: Okay. I checked after loading, and the only two new JS files (of significance) are `mootools-more.js` and another one relating to a calendar plugin I use. I know the menu was failing previous to installing the calendar, so that's ruled out. I disable Mootools to test and now the menu works, so great. I still have a problem in that I'm getting a couple of console errors because Joomla uses Mootools for image captions, but I'll figure that out. Main thing is you identified the problem, so thanks. :D